# Design time error in form for object with

Tags: c#

I have an control that inherits from another control (TxTextControl). I have a SelectedText property that basicaly wraps the base SelectedText property, which is apparently needed because my control is implementing an interface with that property. The code is this:

```
public string SelectedText
{
  get
  {
    return base.Selection.Text; // Error here (#1042)
  }
  set
  {
    if (base.Selection == null)
    {
      base.Selection = new TXTextControl.Selection(0, 0);
    }
    base.Selection.Text = value;
  }
}
```

When I drop this control on a form, no problems. It compiles and runs.  Everything looks great. However, when I save, close then reopen the form, the form designer shows this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   1.   Hide Call Stack
>
> at Test.FormattedTextBox2.get_SelectedText() in C:\Projects\Test\FormattedTextBox2.cs:line 1042

Anyone know what is going on?  I'm about to pull out my last hair...

UPDATE:
darkassisin93's answer wasn't exactly correct, but that was because my posted code wasn't exactly accurate.  I needed to test if base.Selection was null before attempting to access a property of that object. In any case, that answer got me headed in the right direction.  Here is the actual solution:

```
public string SelectedText
{
  get
  {
    string selected = string.Empty;
    if (base.Selection != null)
    {
      selected = base.Selection.Text;
    }
    return selected; 
  }
  set
  {
    if (base.Selection == null)
    {
      base.Selection = new TXTextControl.Selection(0, 0);
      // Have to check here again..this apparently still 
      // results in a null in some cases.
      if (base.Selection == null) return;
    }
    base.Selection.Text = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the contents of FormattedTextBox2.cs, especially line 1042 ?

Comment: Updated question to indicate that error was related to posted code and the line were is occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
return base.SelectedText;
```

with

```
return base.SelectedText ?? string.Empty;
```

It's most likely because the base class's `SelectedText` property is set to null.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't do it, but it got me headed in the write direction. I'll updated my question to reflect actual solution. It was indeed a null issue and once I got that tested for, it now works.